# How to combine multiple pattern searches and produce a single line output using $regex in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

[image]

I am importing a text file and pulling only data I need. I made a pattern that will find the information I am looking for. However, I want all the data I pull per row to all be on the same line when it is output. Is there a way to keep the program from making a new line each time it finds a pattern? The output file should have the ID, Name, and Section per line.

[image]

Comment: PLEASE ...do not post pics of code/errors/data. this is a _code oriented site_, not a picture site. why force others to zoom in or squint to read  your IMAGE of text that you already have as text? do you REALLY expect those who want to help you to type in what you already have as text? [*frown*]

Answer (score 0):

Each solution presented assumes all data about an individual person exists on a single line.

Since each output from [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) will be one [MatchInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=pscore-6.2.0) object per line in the file, you can just join the `Value` property values for each object.

```
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
    Foreach-Object {$_.Matches.Value -join ","} > $output_file
```

All of this assumes that the order of your matches is predictable in your file. If they differ from that schema, then this becomes slightly more complex.

---

If you would change up your regex to use named capture groups, your results could be more predictable with an unordered file. You still need to maintain a field format in the file though.

```
$regex = '\b(?<ID>\d{8})\b|\b(?<Name>[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\b|\b(?<Section>[A-Z]+\d{3})\b'

Select-String -Path t.txt -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
    Foreach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Matches.Groups.where{$_.Success}
    $ID = $groups.where{$_.Name -eq 'ID'}.Value
    $Name = $groups.where{$_.Name -eq 'Name'}.Value
    $Section = $groups.where{$_.Name -eq 'Section'}.Value
    $ID,$Name,$Section -join ","
    }
```

The code above uses named capture groups with the syntax `(?<captureName>)`.

---

Another alternative is to just use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6) statement with `-Regex` and `-File` parameters. Then capture groups do not even matter, but each regex must have a match per line.

```
$output = switch -Regex -File $input_File {
    '\b\d{8}\b' {
        $ID = $matches[0]
    }

    '\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b' {
        $Name = $matches[0]
    }
    '\b[A-Z]+\d{3}\b' {
        $Section = $matches[0]
    }
    '$' {
        $ID,$Name,$Section -join ","
    }
}
$output > $output_file
```

Comment: there is another solution that uses `Get-Content ` & `-ReadCount` ... but does not use regex as the OP seems to prefer. do you think it proper to add that?

Comment: Sure. The more options the better I say.

Comment: arg! i misinterpreted the OP - i thot the 2nd image was the _input_. ... never mind ... [*blush*]